# Different background slides for mobile/screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, slider

I want to have a different set of image display when your are on a mobile device. I am using Vegas Jquery Slider http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

My questions is a bit vague, and I could find what I am needing. Would I just use the window size jquery? or an if.. else... statement?

Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.vegas('slideshow', {
backgrounds:[
  { src:'img/familyoutsidehome5-dark.jpg', fade:1000 },
  { src:'img/familyoutsidehome3-dark.jpg', fade:1000 },
  { src:'img/familyoutsidehome4-dark.jpg', fade:1000 },
  { src:'img/familyoutsidehome-dark.jpg', fade:1000 }
]
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$.vegas.defaults = {
 background: {
   src:         null, // defined by Css
   align:       'center',
   valign:      'center',
   fade:        0,
   loading      true,
   load:        function(){},
   complete:    function(){}
 },
 slideshow: {
   step:        0,
   delay:       5000,
   backgrounds: [],
   preload:     false,
   walk:        function(){}
 },
 overlay: {
   src:         null, // defined by Css 
   opacity:     null  // defined by Css 
 }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, what you want is the website being responsive based on the screen size. You don't even need to use javascript. css `media`can do it:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) and (max-height: 500px) {
  div.element1 {
    background-image: url('background1.png');
  }

  div.element2 {
    background-image: url('background2.png');
  }
}
```

And you can just change the classes in javascript to change background image.

If you want to add transition effects you can also do it in CSS3 by adding a transition:

```
div.element {
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that what I am asking. I want to be able to load an entirely different set images when on a mobile device using the same script above.